# How use datamart to create data warehouse?

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, datamart

I really need help, my situation is:
- have data marts, and need to create data-warehouse from it
- i know only how to create DWH start from transactional DB - ETL - data-warehouse- datamart
- i have no idea what to do about the reversible action. DM - data-warehouse
- im using MSSQL, visual studio
- what should i do? just merge every datamart into data-warehouseand remove redundancy manually?

Comment: Are the dimensions conformed? Please explain your redundancy problem

Comment: "Data Warehouse" is such a nebulous term. In Kimball-world, a data warehouse is simply a collection of fact tables that have conformed dimensions across them. In an Inmon-world, a data warehouse is a 3nf (or higher) database describing the entire enterprise.